# Multiplying value if true

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a payroll script and on top of the default pay, there's a bonus pay.

However, for that bonus pay there is a condition you must meet:

```
df['Qualified'] = df['Average Parcels'].apply(lambda x: 'Qualified' if 10 >= x < 18 else 'Not Qualified')
```

Now for ID's that are qualified, I'd like to multiply the number of orders fulfilled by 1.20.

I've tried something like this but I get a syntax error:

```
df['Extra'] = df['Orders'].apply(lambda x: x * 1.2 if ['Qualified'] == 'Qualified')
```

I'm not sure if doing it this way is the most efficient way, I'm open to other ideas. I'm still new to Python and Pandas so thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't you mean `if df['Qualified'] == 'Qualified'`

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Thanks for your response, even when I do df['Qualified'], I get invalid syntax. I wasn't sure how to express last bit where it's if 'Qualified' then multiply x with 1.2

Comment: `if 10 >= x < 18` is a strange condition. Did you mean `if 10 <= x < 18`, i.e. between 10 (inclusive) and 18 (exclusive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create the "Qualified" column, you can directly get the "Extra" column:

```
df["Extra"] = df["Orders"].mul(1.2).where(df["Average Parcels"].between(10, 18, "left"), 0)
```

Full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Average Parcels": np.random.randint(1, 100, size=15),
                   "Orders": np.random.randint(1, 100, size=15)})

df["Extra"] = df["Orders"].mul(1.2).where(df["Average Parcels"].between(10, 18, "left"), 0)

>>> df
    Average Parcels  Orders  Extra
0                 9      25    0.0
1                25      16    0.0
2                68      61    0.0
3                88      59    0.0
4                80      17    0.0
5                49      10    0.0
6                11      94  112.8
7                95      87    0.0
8                53       3    0.0
9                99      28    0.0
10               54       5    0.0
11               67      32    0.0
12               99       2    0.0
13               15      14   16.8
14               35      84    0.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried the first line and it executed fine but it still applies the extra bonus for each ID instead of picking out the ones that have orders between 10 and 18. Also what does the "left" part do in the code?

Comment: @cchev - Please see the example. It works as expected for me. I've also been editing the answer though, so make sure you're using the current version.

Comment: Happy to help @cchev ! :)

Comment: Sorry, could you explain to me what the "left" and the final ,0) does in the code? Also could I use the same code if I wanted to have a max of 10 instead of between 10 and 18? Could I just replace between with max?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html). "left" means to include the left limit (i.e. 10). The final 0 fills in 0 where the condition is not True. To use <=10, you can use `df["Average Parcels"].le(10)`. Please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments however: new question, new post.